# Beginner's Snake Game using SFML and C++

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, snake-game, sfml

Never really got past the beginner stage of programming so I'm trying to get better this Summer. I think games are a fun way to learn how to program so I decided to start with snake. I'd appreciate any feedback or learning resources you guys think might be helpful. Cheers!

**How it Works**

From the menu screen, when the user presses play, the game initializes (the snake body, food generator, and game clock are dynamically allocated). I keep these game elements in an anonymous namespace but I'm not sure if that's appropriate. After initialization, the game loop runs. Basically, Check for Collisions -> Check if Eating -> Update Snake Nodes -> Render and Display.

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

namespace
{
    SnakeBody *snakebody;
    FoodGenerator *foodgenerator;
    sf::Clock *gameclock;
}

void Game::Start()
{
    if (mGameState != UNINITIALIZED)
        return;

    mMainWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(windowparameters::RESOLUTION_X, windowparameters::RESOLUTION_Y, windowparameters::COLOR_DEPTH), "Snake!");
    mGameState = SHOWING_MENU;

    while (mGameState != EXITING)
        GameLoop();

    mMainWindow.close();
}

void Game::ShowMenuScreen()
{
    MainMenu menuScreen;
    MainMenu::MenuResult result = menuScreen.Show(mMainWindow);

    switch (result)
    {
    case MainMenu::Exit:
        mGameState = EXITING;
        break;

    case MainMenu::Play:
        mGameState = RUNNING;
        break;
    }
}

Game::GameState Game::WaitForEnterOrExit()
{
    GameState nextstate = GAMEOVER;
    sf::Event currentevent;

    while (nextstate != EXITING && nextstate != RUNNING)
    {
        while (mMainWindow.pollEvent(currentevent))
        {
            if (currentevent.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed && 
                sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Enter))
            {
                nextstate = RUNNING;
            }
            else if (currentevent.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
            {
                nextstate = EXITING;
            }
        }
    }

    return nextstate;
}

void Game::InitializeGameElements()
{
    snakebody = new SnakeBody();
    foodgenerator = new FoodGenerator(windowparameters::RESOLUTION_X, windowparameters::RESOLUTION_Y, windowparameters::UNIT_SPACING);
    gameclock = new sf::Clock();
}

void Game::CleanupGameElements()
{
    delete(gameclock);
    delete(snakebody);
    delete(foodgenerator);
}

void Game::HandleEvents()
{
    sf::Event currentevent;

    while (mMainWindow.pollEvent(currentevent))
    {
        if (currentevent.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed)
        {
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
            {
                snakebody->RedirectHead(SnakeBody::LEFT);
            }
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
            {
                snakebody->RedirectHead(SnakeBody::RIGHT);
            }
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
            {
                snakebody->RedirectHead(SnakeBody::UP);
            }
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
            {
                snakebody->RedirectHead(SnakeBody::DOWN);
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (currentevent.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
        {
            mGameState = EXITING;
            mMainWindow.close();
        }
    }
}

void Game::GameTick()
{
    // tick scene
    if (gameclock->getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() >= windowparameters::TIC_RATE_IN_MS)
    {
        // Check Collision with body
        if (snakebody->CheckCollision())
            mGameState = GAMEOVER;

        else if (snakebody->CheckEating(foodgenerator->mGraphic))
        {
            snakebody->IncrementSegments();
            foodgenerator->mUneaten = false;

            std::cout << "SCORE = " << snakebody->mNumSegments << std::endl;
        }

        // update snake
        snakebody->UpdateSegments(0, windowparameters::RESOLUTION_X, 0, windowparameters::RESOLUTION_Y);

        // update food
        if (!foodgenerator->mUneaten)
            foodgenerator->Generate(snakebody);

        // reset screen, render, display
        mMainWindow.clear(sf::Color(230, 230, 230));

        mMainWindow.draw(foodgenerator->mGraphic);
        snakebody->DrawSegments(mMainWindow);

        mMainWindow.display();
        gameclock->restart();
    }
}

void Game::GameLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        switch (mGameState)
        {
        case SHOWING_MENU:
            ShowMenuScreen();
            break;

        case GAMEOVER:
            mGameState = WaitForEnterOrExit();
            break;

        case RUNNING:

            InitializeGameElements();

            // run game loop
            while (mMainWindow.isOpen() && mGameState == RUNNING)
            {
                HandleEvents();
                GameTick();
            }

            CleanupGameElements();
            break;

        case EXITING:
            mMainWindow.close();
            break;

        default:
            mMainWindow.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Because Game is a static class, the member variables need to be instantiated MANUALLY
Game::GameState Game::mGameState = Game::UNINITIALIZED;
sf::RenderWindow Game::mMainWindow;
```

**Game.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

#include "FoodGenerator.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"
#include "SFML\Window.hpp"
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "SnakeBody.h"

namespace windowparameters
{
    const uint16_t RESOLUTION_X = 1024;
    const uint16_t RESOLUTION_Y = 768;
    const uint8_t COLOR_DEPTH = 32;
    const uint16_t TIC_RATE_IN_MS = 60;
    const uint8_t UNIT_SPACING = 32;
}

class Game
{
public:
    static void Start();

private:
    enum GameState { UNINITIALIZED, SHOWING_MENU, RUNNING, EXITING, GAMEOVER };

    static void GameLoop();
    static void ShowMenuScreen();
    static void InitializeGameElements();
    static void CleanupGameElements();
    static void HandleEvents();
    static void GameTick();
    static GameState WaitForEnterOrExit();

    static GameState mGameState;
    static sf::RenderWindow mMainWindow;
};
```

**FoodGenerator.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <random>

#include "Coordinate.h"
#include "SnakeBody.h"

class FoodGenerator
{
public:
    FoodGenerator::FoodGenerator(int xmax, int ymax, int spacing);
    Coordinate Generate(SnakeBody *snakeBody);
    bool mUneaten;
    int mXMax;
    int mYMax;
    int mSpacing;
    Coordinate mCurrentLocation;
    sf::RectangleShape mGraphic;

private:
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniX;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniY;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng;
};
```

**FoodGenerator.cpp**

```
#include "FoodGenerator.h"

FoodGenerator::FoodGenerator(int xmax, int ymax, int spacing)
{
    rng = std::mt19937(rd());    // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
    uniX = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(1, xmax/spacing - 1); // guaranteed unbiased
    uniY = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(1, ymax/spacing - 1); // guaranteed unbiased

    mGraphic = sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(spacing, spacing));
    mGraphic.setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 128));
    mGraphic.setOrigin(0, 0);

    mUneaten = false;
    mXMax = xmax;
    mYMax = ymax;
    mSpacing = spacing;
}

Coordinate FoodGenerator::Generate(SnakeBody *snakeBody)
{
    bool freePosFound = false;
    int xPos, yPos;

    std::list<SnakeBody::SnakeSegment>::iterator it, head, end;
    it = snakeBody->mSegments.begin();
    head = snakeBody->mSegments.begin();
    end = snakeBody->mSegments.end();

    while (!freePosFound)
    {
        xPos = uniX(rng);
        yPos = uniY(rng);

        mGraphic.setPosition(xPos*mSpacing, yPos*mSpacing);

        while (it != end)
        {
            if (it->mGraphic.getGlobalBounds().intersects(mGraphic.getGlobalBounds()))
            {
                it = head;
                break;
            }

            it++;
        }

        if (it == end)
            freePosFound = true;
    }
    mUneaten = true;
    return Coordinate(xPos, yPos);
}
```

**MainMenu.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <list>

#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"

class MainMenu
{
public:
    enum MenuResult {Nothing, Exit, Play};

    struct MenuItem
    {
        MenuResult action;
        sf::Rect<int> rect;
    };

    MenuResult Show(sf::RenderWindow& window);

private:
    MenuResult GetMenuResponse(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    MenuResult HandleClick(int x, int y);
    std::list<MenuItem> mMenuItems;
};
```

**MainMenu.cpp**

```
#include "MainMenu.h"

MainMenu::MenuResult MainMenu::Show(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    sf::Texture image;
    image.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Carter/Pictures/snake_menu.jpg");
    sf::Sprite sprite(image);

    MenuItem playButton;
    playButton.rect.left = 200;
    playButton.rect.top = 525;
    playButton.rect.width = 600;
    playButton.rect.height = 100;
    playButton.action = Play;

    MenuItem exitButton;
    exitButton.rect.left = 200;
    exitButton.rect.top = 630;
    exitButton.rect.width = 600;
    exitButton.rect.height = 100;
    exitButton.action = Exit;

    mMenuItems.push_back(playButton);
    mMenuItems.push_back(exitButton);

    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();

    return GetMenuResponse(window);
}

MainMenu::MenuResult MainMenu::HandleClick(int x, int y)
{
    std::list<MenuItem>::iterator it;

    for (it = mMenuItems.begin(); it != mMenuItems.end(); it++)
    {
        sf::Rect<int> menuItemRect = (*it).rect;

        if((x > menuItemRect.left) &&
            (x < (menuItemRect.left + menuItemRect.width)) &&
            (y > menuItemRect.top) &&
            (y < (menuItemRect.top + menuItemRect.height)))
        {
            return (*it).action;
        }
    }
    return Nothing;
}

MainMenu::MenuResult MainMenu::GetMenuResponse(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    sf::Event menuEvent;

    while (true)
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(menuEvent))
        {
            if (menuEvent.type == sf::Event::EventType::MouseButtonPressed)
                return HandleClick(menuEvent.mouseButton.x, menuEvent.mouseButton.y);

            if (menuEvent.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
                return Exit;
        }
    }
}
```

**SnakeBody.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <list>

#include "Coordinate.h"
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"


class SnakeBody
{
public:
    SnakeBody();

    enum SnakeDirection { LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };

    class SnakeSegment
    {
    public:
        SnakeSegment(int x, int y, SnakeDirection dir);
        void UpdatePosition();
        bool CheckBounds(int xmin, int xmax, int ymin, int ymax);
        Coordinate GetPosition();
        void SetPosition(int x, int y);
        SnakeDirection GetDirection();
        void SetDirection(SnakeDirection dir);

        sf::RectangleShape mGraphic;

    private:
        Coordinate mPosition;
        SnakeDirection mDirection;
    };

    void UpdateSegments(int xmin, int xmax, int ymin, int ymax);
    void DrawSegments(sf::RenderWindow &window);
    void RedirectHead(SnakeDirection newDir);
    void IncrementSegments();
    bool CheckCollision();
    bool CheckEating(sf::RectangleShape foodGraphic);

    int mNumSegments;
    std::list<SnakeSegment> mSegments;
};
```

**SnakeBody.cpp**

```
#include "SnakeBody.h"

namespace
{
    const uint8_t SNAKE_MOVE_PER_TICK = 32;
    const uint8_t BODY_DIM = 32;
}

SnakeBody::SnakeSegment::SnakeSegment(int x, int y, SnakeBody::SnakeDirection dir)
{
    SetPosition(x, y);
    SetDirection(dir);

    mGraphic = sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(BODY_DIM, BODY_DIM));
    mGraphic.setFillColor(sf::Color(34, 139, 34));
    mGraphic.setOrigin(BODY_DIM / 2, BODY_DIM / 2);
    mGraphic.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x, y));
}

Coordinate SnakeBody::SnakeSegment::GetPosition()
{
    return mPosition;
}

void SnakeBody::SnakeSegment::SetPosition(int x, int y)
{
    mPosition.mXCoord = x;
    mPosition.mYCoord = y;
    mGraphic.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x, y));
}

SnakeBody::SnakeDirection SnakeBody::SnakeSegment::GetDirection()
{
    return mDirection;
}

void SnakeBody::SnakeSegment::SetDirection(SnakeBody::SnakeDirection dir)
{
    // prevent 180 degree turns about the head
    switch (dir)
    {
    case LEFT:
        if (mDirection == RIGHT)
            return;
        break;

    case RIGHT:
        if (mDirection == LEFT)
            return;
        break;

    case UP:
        if (mDirection == DOWN)
            return;
        break;

    case DOWN:
        if (mDirection == UP)
            return;
        break;
    }

    SnakeSegment::mDirection = dir;
}

bool SnakeBody::SnakeSegment::CheckBounds(int xmin, int xmax, int ymin, int ymax)
{
    bool wrapped = false;
    int xrange = xmax - xmin;
    int yrange = ymax - ymin;

    // check bounds and wrap
    if (mPosition.mXCoord < xmin)
    {
        mPosition.mXCoord += xrange;
        wrapped = true;
    }
    else if (mPosition.mXCoord > xmax)
    {
        mPosition.mXCoord %= xrange;
        wrapped = true;
    }
    else if (mPosition.mYCoord < ymin)
    {
        mPosition.mYCoord += yrange;
        wrapped = true;
    }

    else if (mPosition.mYCoord > ymax)
    {
        mPosition.mYCoord %= yrange;
        wrapped = true;
    }

    if(wrapped)
        mGraphic.setPosition(mPosition.mXCoord, mPosition.mYCoord);

    return wrapped;
}


void SnakeBody::SnakeSegment::UpdatePosition()
{
    // check direction and increment
    switch (mDirection)
    {
    case LEFT:
        mPosition.IncrementX(-SNAKE_MOVE_PER_TICK);
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        mPosition.IncrementX(SNAKE_MOVE_PER_TICK);
        break;
    case UP:
        mPosition.IncrementY(-SNAKE_MOVE_PER_TICK);
        break;
    case DOWN:
        mPosition.IncrementY(SNAKE_MOVE_PER_TICK);
        break;
    }

    mGraphic.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(mPosition.mXCoord, mPosition.mYCoord));
}

SnakeBody::SnakeBody()
{
    SnakeBody::SnakeSegment headSegment(BODY_DIM/2, BODY_DIM/2, RIGHT);
    //SnakeBody::SnakeSegment testSegment(100 - BODY_DIM, 100, RIGHT);
    mNumSegments = 1;
    mSegments.push_back(headSegment);
    //_segments.push_back(testSegment);
}

void SnakeBody::UpdateSegments(int xmin, int xmax, int ymin, int ymax)
{
    // update segments starting at tail
    std::list<SnakeSegment>::iterator front, it, next, end;
    it = --mSegments.end();
    end = mSegments.end();

    if (mNumSegments > 1)
        next = --(--mSegments.end());
    else
        next = end;

    front = mSegments.begin();

    for(int i=0; i < mNumSegments; i++)
    {
        // increment position
        it->UpdatePosition();
        it->CheckBounds(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax);

        // update direction for non-head nodes
        if ((it != front) && (it->GetDirection() != next->GetDirection())){
            it->SetDirection(next->GetDirection());
        }

        if ((next != front) && next != end)
            next--;

        if (it != front)
            it--;
    }
}

void SnakeBody::DrawSegments(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    std::list<SnakeSegment>::iterator it = mSegments.begin();
    std::list<SnakeSegment>::iterator end = mSegments.end();

    while (it != end)
    {
        window.draw(it->mGraphic);
        it++;
    }

}

void SnakeBody::RedirectHead(SnakeBody::SnakeDirection newDir)
{
    std::list<SnakeSegment>::iterator head = mSegments.begin();
    head->SetDirection(newDir);
}

void SnakeBody::IncrementSegments()
{
    // find location of last node
    std::list<SnakeSegment>::iterator tail = --mSegments.end();

    // spawn at offset location
    int newX, newY;
    newX = (tail->GetPosition()).mXCoord;
    newY = (tail->GetPosition()).mYCoord;

    switch (tail->GetDirection())
    {
    case LEFT:
        newX += BODY_DIM;
        break;
    case RIGHT: 
        newX -= BODY_DIM;
        break;
    case UP:
        newY += BODY_DIM;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        newY -= BODY_DIM;
        break;
    }
    SnakeSegment newSegment(newX, newY, tail->GetDirection());
    mSegments.push_back(newSegment);
    mNumSegments++;
}

bool SnakeBody::CheckCollision()
{
    sf::RectangleShape headRect = (mSegments.begin())->mGraphic;
    std::list<SnakeSegment>::iterator it = ++mSegments.begin();

    for (int i = 1; i < mNumSegments; i++, it++)
    {
        if (headRect.getGlobalBounds().intersects(it->mGraphic.getGlobalBounds()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool SnakeBody::CheckEating(sf::RectangleShape foodGraphic)
{
    std::list<SnakeSegment>::iterator head = mSegments.begin();

    return head->mGraphic.getGlobalBounds().intersects(foodGraphic.getGlobalBounds());
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    Game::Start();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open as OP's added the rest of the code.

Comment: The only thing currently missing appears to be `Coordinate.h`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Understand how `#include` works

On most platforms, the difference between `#include "iostream"` and `#include <iostream>` is that the former looks first in the current directory.  So for system files such as `SFML/Graphics.hpp`, you should really use `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` instead.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162030/difference-between-angle-bracket-and-double-quotes-while-including-heade) for more details.

### Don't hardcode file names

Generally, it's not a good idea to hardcode a file name in software, and generally especially bad if it's an absolute file name (as contrasted with one with a relative path).  Instead, it would be better to allow the user of the program to specify the name, as with a command line parameter.  This line:

```
image.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Carter/Pictures/snake_menu.jpg");
```

will fail on every computer which a) isn't running Windows and b) doesn't have that exact file in that exact location.  That's not good for portability!

### Simplify your code

Right now the code to handle clicking on the menu screen is this:

```
MainMenu::MenuResult MainMenu::HandleClick(int x, int y)
{
        std::list<MenuItem>::iterator it;

        for (it = mMenuItems.begin(); it != mMenuItems.end(); it++)
        {
                sf::Rect<int> menuItemRect = (*it).rect;

                if((x > menuItemRect.left) &&
                        (x < (menuItemRect.left + menuItemRect.width)) &&
                        (y > menuItemRect.top) &&
                        (y < (menuItemRect.top + menuItemRect.height)))
                {
                        return (*it).action;
                }
        }
        return Nothing;
}
```

That is *much* longer and more complex than it needs to be.  First, let's use a "range-for" instead of an iterator:

```
MainMenu::MenuResult MainMenu::HandleClick(int x, int y)
{
    for (const auto box : mMenuItems)
    {
        if((x > box.rect.left) &&
                (x < (box.rect.left + box.rect.width)) &&
                (y > box.rect.top) &&
                (y < (box.rect.top + box.rect.height)))
        {
            return rect.action;
        }
    }
    return Nothing;
}
```

### Use SFML more effectively

Next, let's use the SFML `Rect` class to further simplify the code:

```
MainMenu::MenuResult MainMenu::HandleClick(int x, int y) {
    for (const auto box : mMenuItems) {
        if(box.rect.contains(x, y)) {
            return box.action;
        }
    }
    return Nothing;
}
```

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

There are a few numbers in the code, such as `200` and `100` that have a specific meaning in their particular context.  By using named constants such as `ButtonLeft` or `ButtonHeight`, the program becomes easier to read and maintain.  For cases in which the constant only has sense with respect to a particular object, consider making that constant part of the object.

### Choose appropriate data structure

The value of a `std::list` is that it allows constant time insertion and removal of items.  However, this is *not* what is needed or desired from a menu.  In fact, it could be a `const` array like this:

```
const std::array<MenuItem,2> mMenuItems {{
    { Play, {200, 525, 600, 100}},
    { Exit, {200, 400, 600, 100}},
}};
```

You'll note that while the original menu item rectangles were overlapping, these do not.

### Prefer modern initializers for constructors

The constructor for `SnakeSegment` and probably others can be simplified with default values and a parameter intialization style.  Example:

```
SnakeBody::SnakeSegment::SnakeSegment(int x, int y, SnakeBody::SnakeDirection dir) :
    mGraphic{sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(BODY_DIM, BODY_DIM))},
    mPosition{x, y}, 
    mDirection{dir} 
{
        mGraphic.setFillColor(sf::Color(34, 139, 34));
        mGraphic.setOrigin(BODY_DIM / 2, BODY_DIM / 2);
        mGraphic.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x, y));
}
```

This also eliminates the need for a `SetPosition` member function.

### Don't write getters and setters for every class

C++ isn't Java and writing getter and setter functions for every C++ class is not good style. Instead, move setter functionality into constructors and think very carefully about whether a getter is needed at all. In this code, t's easy to remove `SnakeSegment` functions `GetPosition`, `SetPosition`, and `GetDirection`.  Also, by declaring `friend SnakeBody;` within `SnakeSegment`, all remaining functions and data members except `mGraphic` can be declared `private`.

### Actually quit the program

When the user selects "Exit" from the menu, the game should actually quit, and not just close the window.

There's more, but this is all I have time for at the moment.